# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade problem

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

Yesterday I decided to do the upgrade. Little did I know, I got a black out, the upgrade was interrupted and the rest is history. Now I am facing the following issues:
1) No GUI when I open up the pc I am presented with the terminal, I log in every file seems in place but no GUI. Seems that Unity is not installed. I try to install it but then I bumb up to the second error
2) No internet connectivity (wired and wireless). When on `ifconfig -a` I only get `lo`. I downloaded the drivers, compiled them but still no luck. Really need your help on this.

Laptop Lenovo G550

Broadcom BCM4312
Realtek RTL8101E

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: @saiarcot895 Unmet dependencies: Unity but is not going to be installed. That's the output I get.

Comment: @sbergeron It fails to fetch everything. Probably because of no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading an image on a flash drive using something like YUMI. Boot from the drive and select rescue a broken system. Follow the steps :)

Comment: I recommend expanding this answer with a more detailed explanation of how to do this.